# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' en Python 3 (think stats program brfss.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x

seguro por el titulo pensaran que esta es una pregunta repetida, sin embargo los problemas que he visto aquí no se parecen a mi problema. El código es el siguiente:

```
import math
import sys
import survey
import thinkstats

class Respondents(survey.Table):
   def ReadRecords(self, data_dir='.', n=None):
      filename = self.GetFilename()
      self.ReadFile(data_dir,
                  filename,
                  self.GetFields(),
                  survey.Respondent,
                  n)
       self.Recode()
   def GetFilename(self):
       return 'CDBRFS08.ASC.gz'

   def GetFields(self):
       return [
        ('age', 101, 102, int),
        ('weight2', 119, 122, int),
        ('wtyrago', 127, 130, int),
        ('wtkg2', 1254, 1258, int),
        ('htm3', 1251, 1253, int),
        ('sex', 143, 143, int),
        ]
   def Recode(self):
       def CleanWeight(weight):
        if weight in [7777, 9999]:
            return 'NA'
        elif weight < 1000:
            return weight / 2.2
        elif 9000 < weight < 9999:
            return weight - 9000
        else:
            return weight

    for rec in self.records:
        # recode wtkg2
        if rec.wtkg2 in ['NA', 99999]:
            rec.wtkg2 = 'NA'
        else:
            rec.wtkg2 /= 100.0

        # recode wtyrago
        rec.weight2 = CleanWeight(rec.weight2)
        rec.wtyrago = CleanWeight(rec.wtyrago)

        # recode htm3
        if rec.htm3 == 999:
            rec.htm3 = 'NA'

        # recode age
        if rec.age in [7, 9]:
            rec.age = 'NA'
   def SummarizeHeight(self):
       d = {1:[], 2:[], 'all':[]}
    [d[r.sex].append(r.htm3) for r in self.records if r.htm3 != 'NA']
    [d['all'].append(r.htm3) for r in self.records if r.htm3 != 'NA']

    print('Height (cm):')
    print('key n     mean     var    sigma     cv')
    for key, t in d.iteritems():
        mu, var = thinkstats.TrimmedMeanVar(t)
        sigma = math.sqrt(var)
        cv = sigma / mu
        print(key, len(t), mu, var, sigma, cv)

    return d
   def SummarizeWeight(self):
       d = {1:[], 2:[], 'all':[]}
    [d[r.sex].append(r.weight2) for r in self.records if r.weight2 != 'NA']
    [d['all'].append(r.weight2) for r in self.records if r.weight2 != 'NA']

    print('Weight (kg):')
    print('key n     mean     var    sigma     cv')
    for key, t in d.iteritems():
        mu, var = thinkstats.TrimmedMeanVar(t)
        sigma = math.sqrt(var)
        cv = sigma / mu
        print(key, len(t), mu, var, sigma, cv)
   def SummarizeWeightChange(self):
       data = [(r.weight2, r.wtyrago) for r in self.records
            if r.weight2 != 'NA' and r.wtyrago != 'NA']

    changes = [(curr - prev) for curr, prev in data]

    print('Mean change', thinkstats.Mean(changes))
def main(name, data_dir='.'):
resp = Respondents()
resp.ReadRecords(data_dir)
resp.SummarizeHeight()
resp.SummarizeWeight()
resp.SummarizeWeightChange()

if __name__ == '__main__':
main(*sys.argv)
```

Este problema es parte del libro thinkstats de Allen B. Downey, dicho problema estaba escrito en python2 pero ya le hice alguans modificaciones para python3. Sin embargo, al compilar el codigo me aparece el error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Ya me leí varios post de aquí (ya se que el problema se debe a que estoy comparando un srt con un int) pero la diferencia es que dichos posts le dan a la variable un valor que introduce el usuario, en mi caso, estoy extrayendo mis datos de un archivo .ASC.gz, por lo que las sugerencias que me dan no me han servido tanto. He intentando algunas modificaciones en la parte conflictiva, una de ellas es:

```
   def CleanWeight(weight):
        if int(weight) in [7777, 9999]:
            return 'NA'
        elif int(weight) < 1000:
            return int(weight) / 2.2
        elif 9000 < int(weight) < 9999:
            return int(weight) - 9000
        else:
            return int(weight)
```

Sin embargo, despues de haber hecho esto ahora me marca el error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'
```

Tambien he intentado reenombrar la variable:

```
   def CleanWeight(weight):
        w = int(weight)
        if w in [7777, 9999]:
            return 'NA'
        elif w < 1000:
            return w / 2.2
        elif 9000 < w < 9999:
            return w - 9000
        else:
            return w
```

Pero otra vez obtengo el mismo error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'
```

La verdad es que ya no se que hacer, espero y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que los valores `"NA"` no pueden convertirse a `int`, solo `float` y `decimal.Decimal` permite almacenar valores NaN. (`float("nan")` y `decimal.Decimal('nan')`). Las series de datos que contengan la cadena `"NA"` deberían ser convertidas a `float` y los `"NA"` convertidos a `float('nan')` en un principio.

Comment: Hola, ya he hecho el camio, ahora puse `float(weight)` en todos los lugares donde había `weight`. Sin embargo, ahora me manda el error ´ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'NA'´.:(

Comment: `"NA"` no es una cadena válida, debe ser `"nan"`, `"NaN"` o `"NAN"`. Usa un condicional, por ejemplo:  `valor = float("nan") if weight == "NA" else float(weight)`. O un try-except: `try:
    valor = float(weight)
except ValueError:
    valor = float("nan")` (el bloque try-except debe ser identado correctamente, los comentarios no permiten mantener la identación...)

Comment: Hola de nuevo, gracias por tu paciencia, la verdad soy algo nuevo en python, ¿podrías ser mas especifico y decirme en donde tengo que poner el condicional que mencionaste?  Yo supongo que debe ser en la parte conflictiva (en este caso, dentro de la función `CleanWeight`, pero si estoy mal por favor corrígeme). Ahora, sobre los `"NA"` y los `"NaN"`, ¿esos cambios los tengo que hacer dentro de el archivo ASC? Si es así,¿sabes como lo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si python te esta diciendo que el problema esta en la función CleanWeith, lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

```
def CleanWeight(weight):
    # weight es una cadena de texto
    if not str(weight).isnumeric(): # comprobamos si la cadena de texto no contiene un número, de ser así, devuelve que no es un número (he puesto 'NA' para seguir tu nomenclatura pero debiera ser NaN)
        return 'NA'
    w = int(weight)
    if w in [7777, 9999]:
        return 'NA'
    elif w < 1000:
        return w / 2.2
    elif 9000 < w < 9999:
        return w - 9000
    else:
        return w
```

Como puedes ver antes de ejecutar ninguna operación he comprobado si el dato introducido era un número.

Otra opción menos limpia pero igual de valida es usar try: except:, puedes buscar en la documentación de python sobre ello

Comment: Hola, muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, con esto el programa ya funciona.